# Smallness of cut-off functions at critical Sobolev regularity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Consider the class of functions

$$X:=\{f\in \mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\;s.t.\;f\equiv 1  \mbox{ in a neighbourhood of}\;\;x=0\}$$

**Is it true that, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, I can find $f\in X$ such that $\|f\|_{H^{1/2}(\mathbb{R})}<\varepsilon$?**

For $s\in[0,1/2)$, it is easy to show that the analogous question has affirmative answer. Indeed, given $f\in X$ and $n>0$, define $f_n(x):=f(nx)$. Then $f_n\in X$, and $\|f_n\|_{H^{s}(\mathbb{R})}\to 0$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Instead, when $s>1/2$, the analogous question has negative answer. Indeed, by Sobolev embedding one has
$$\|f\|_{H^s}\geqslant C\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}\geqslant C|f(0)|= C$$
for any $f\in X$.

In the critical case $s=1/2$ I think the answer is affirmative, but I'm not able to prove it.
Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well known and easy to verify that (Exercise 14 p. 309 in [1])
$$
\log\Big|\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\Big|\in H^1(B^2(0,e^{-1}))
$$
so the trace of this function on the $x$-axis belongs to the trace space
$$
f(x)=\log\Big|\log|x|\Big|\in H^{1/2}((-e^{-1},e^{-1})).
$$
Let
$$
f_t(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } f(x)\leq t\\
f(x)-t & \text{if } t\leq f(x)\leq 2t\\
t & \text{if } f(x)\geq 2t
\end{cases}
$$
be a truncation of the function $f$ between the levels $t$ and $2t$, $t>0$. Then
$f_t\in H^{1,2}$ and $\Vert f_t\Vert_{1/2}\leq\Vert f\Vert_{1/2}$. 
Indeed, the space $H^{1/2}(\mathbb{R})$ is equipped with the norm
$$
\Vert u\Vert_{1/2}=
\Vert u\Vert_2+
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^2}\, dx\, dy\right)^{1/2}.
$$
Since $|f_t|\leq|f|$ and $|f_t(x)-f_t(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(y)|$, it immediately follows that $\Vert f_t\Vert_{1/2}\leq\Vert f\Vert_{1/2}$. Therefore
$$
\left\Vert\frac{1}{t}f_t\right\Vert_{1/2}\leq \frac{1}{t}\Vert f\Vert_{1/2}\to 0
\quad
\text{as $t\to\infty$.}
$$
The function $t^{-1}f_t$ equals $1$ near $0$ and it has compact support so approximating this function by convolution we can obtain a function $g_t\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g_t=1$ near $0$ and $\Vert g_t\Vert_{1/2}<\varepsilon$, provided $t$ is sufficiently large.

[1] **L. C. Evans,** *Partial differential equations.* Second edition. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 19. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2010.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer! How can I rigorously prove that $\|f_t\|_{1/2}\leq\|f\|_{1/2}$?

Comment: @Capublanca I added details of the proof that $\Vert f_t\Vert_{1/2}\leq\Vert f\Vert_{1/2}$.

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear. There is a typo, an $f(t)$ instead of $f(y)$. I accepted your answer.

Comment: @Capublanca I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 3):

I now think this is indeed possible, and here's a sketch of my current ideas: I want to use the formula
$$
\|f\|_{H^{1/2}}^2 \simeq \|f\|_2^2 + \int\!\!\int \left( \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \right)^2 \, dxdy
$$
to compute the $H^{1/2}$ norms. I'll focus on our function on $x<0$, and I'll let it increase from $0$ to $1$ on $[-\epsilon, 0]$ (in general, it seems clear that passing to the increasing rearrangement will only decrease the $H^{1/2}$ norm).

If we just use a linear function, then we obtain a contribution of $1$ from the double integral. Now split this up (in Cantor function style) and do the increase on two tiny intervals $I_j$ of size $\delta\ll\epsilon$ each, and $f=1/2$ on an interval in the middle of length almost $\epsilon$.

The point is that now the portion of the double integral with $x,y\in I_j$ for fixed $j$ is only $1/4$. There are two of these, so the overall contribution is $1/2$, but that still improves by a factor of $2$ what I had before.

The contributions with $x\in I_j$, $y\notin I_j$ (or the other way around) can be kept small by taking $\delta$ sufficiently small.

Now we can iterate this procedure. It seems clear (but I haven't proved it formally) that my future antics on the $I_j$'s will not dramatically change the contributions discussed in the previous paragraph, so each step should gain me roughly a factor of $2$.

Comment: The result you quote, as stated, is indeed false. The constant in the Sobolev embedding depends on $q$.

Comment: @Capublanca: Ok, thought so, thanks for clarifying (I don't think I misquoted, though, the formulation in the paper clearly seems to assert independence of $q$).

Comment: Sure, in the formulation of the theorem there is no dependence on $q$, but as you said it would imply that $H^{1/2}$ embeds into $L^{\infty}$ which is not the case. Thank you in any case for your answer

Comment: Christian, the idea is very nice! I'm trying to figure out how to make everything rigorous

Comment: @Capublanca: Thanks! In the meantime, it has occurred to me it might be better to organize it like this: Fix a large integer $N$, and then construct a Cantor like set consisting of $2^N$ intervals, but with the gap in the middle being $(1-2\delta_j)$ of the corresponding interval. Now define $f$ in the obvious way, by increasing the value by $1/N$ across each $I_j$. Claim: the double integral will converge to $2^{-N}$ as the $\delta_j$ go to zero. Since we fixed $N$, we now only need to show that for any fixed case that can arise with $x,y$ being somewhere, ... (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) but not both in the same $I_j$, the corresponding double integral can be made arbitrarily small by sending the $\delta_j\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

It is well known that the $H^{1/2}( R)$ norm does not control the $L^\infty$ norm. This means that there exists a sequence of test functions whose $H^{1/2}$ norm tends to zero, and whose maximum value is >2. Since norms are translation invariant, this gives the sequence you are looking for.

Concerning the failure of the continuous embedding $H^{1/2} \subset L^\infty$, the proof I know is indirect and I do not know explicit counterexamples, like the elementary ones e.g. for the failure of $ W^{1,n}(R^n)\subseteq L^\infty(R^n)$ (essentially $\log|x|$), but of course there may be some explicitly constructions.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer Piero! I have a last doubt: are we sure that we can modify the test functions so that they are constant in a neighbourhood of the origin?

Comment: I understand the point, it's essentially the same truncation used by Piotr Hajlasz. I accepted his answer as it also provide an explicit example, but your argument it's quite elegant and clean. Thank you!

Comment: Sure. I suspected that an iterated log might do the trick but I had not time to check.